# Why GCP overrides my /etc/resolv.conf file and how to avoid it?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform

On Google Cloud Platform `/etc/resolv.conf` file being overridden every time I do `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service` or I restart the machine.

Is there a "correct" way to avoid it? or shall I write a script on startup which overrides it back?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why my local DNS is not used?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1051179/why-my-local-dns-is-not-used)

Comment: no adil it is my question but it is different. thanks for reading it before trying to close this one NOT

Comment: Probably relevant: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/manually-configuring-the-etc-resolv-conf-file_configuring-and-managing-networking

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist this is it! i fixed it :) please write it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

The `resolv.conf` options are renewed every 24 hours for global DNS, as per [this official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns#resolv.conf). It is also possible to modify the values, by [editing the DHCP Policy](https://kb.isc.org/docs/isc-dhcp-41-manual-pages-dhclientconf).

For Debian 10, Here are the steps:

1. Edit "/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf"
2. Uncomment the line "supersede domain name", and modify the values of it:
   supersede domain-name "asdf.v1.com";

   *NOTE: supersede will use only your provided details, prepend will use first your values then the server-provided ones, and append will use first the server-provided values, and then your custom ones.*
3. Save the file
4. Restart the DHCP client with the command "sudo dhclient -v -r"

Please keep in mind that these steps might not work for other distributions, make sure to backup and review the steps before performing them.

Comment: why are you talking about dhcp? i use static address. question is - why the file is overriden by GCP. nothing to do with 24hrs.

Comment: @BoppityBop - even though you are using static IP addresses, DHCP is how Google Cloud sets up items like DNS. Note: for Zonal DNS, resolv.conf is overwritten every hour. So yes, 24 hours is correct and applies even to static IP address configurations. This answers recommendation to modify `/etc/dhclient.conf` is correct.

Comment: The issue has been resolved following Hackan link.

Answer (score 2):

You can tell `NetworkManager` not to modify some of the /etc/resolv.conf entries by making changes to the file `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`.

For instance, GCP uses the metadata sever, IP address 169.254.169.254 as the default name sever. You can override the `nameserver` entry of resolv.conf by following below steps -

1. Add `dns=none` entry to /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf file as below -

```
 [main]
 #plugins=ifcfg-rh
 dns=none
```

2. Restart NetworkManager service

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```

3. Modify `/etc/resolv.conf` with your custom nameserver

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

After making these changes, restarting NetworkManger should not override your custom entry.

Answer (score 2):

Following Håkan Lindqvist comment I used symbolic link from paragraph 29.2

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/manually-configuring-the-etc-resolv-conf-file_configuring-and-managing-networking

> NetworkManager does not automatically update the DNS configuration if `/etc/resolv.conf` is a symbolic link. This section describes how to replace `/etc/resolv.conf` with a symbolic link to an alternative file with the DNS configuration.

> 1. Create a file, such as `/etc/resolv.conf.manually-configured`, and add the DNS configuration for your environment to it. Use the same
>    parameters and syntax as in the original `/etc/resolv.conf`.
> 2. Remove the `/etc/resolv.conf` file:
>
>    ```
>    # rm /etc/resolv.conf
>    ```
> 3. Create a symbolic link named `/etc/resolv.conf` that refers to `/etc/resolv.conf.manually-configured`:
>
>    ```
>    # ln -s /etc/resolv.conf.manually-configured /etc/resolv.conf
>    ```